Has anyone ran a pfsense firewall behind a Starlink dish and successfully deployed OpenVPN?
So I've connected my Netgate pfsense firewall directly to my starlink dish (gen 1 router with round dish) successfully, and have WAN/LAN running smoothly. Port1WAN 192.168.
I followed this video and other tutorials rebuilding the OpenVPN configurations multiple times but can't seem to get it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnJgbwZGB8M
I've tried pointing the OpenVPN Export at the WAN port IP, and the IP that resolves when I browse "what's my ip", and I've tried putting ddns..com and putting my Cloudflare API key into my firewall to see if I can get that to connect.
At this point I have no idea what is wrong.
I would appreciate any insight. Has anyone connected to a firewall using OpenVPN going through a Starlink connection?

Yes, you can configure OPENVPN to access your network behind Starlink.
It has to be IPV6 setup (pfsense and Open vpn tunnel).
Also you will have to have DDNS setup for IPV6. I use No-IP  service (free service).
For VPN client config, I had to use this line
proto udp6
and for address entry
remote 'my ddns name'  1194 udp6
